# Bootstrap Affixed nav bar w/ parallax scrolling problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Essentially my website has multiple parallax scrolling panels, so basically a picture embedded within a div element, and splitting between two of those panels, I have a navbar which I want to affix to the top of the screen... now I have that completed but the navbar isn't on the top most layer and all the other divs on the screen go on top of that, there is a "demo" or my site which you can see this actively happening. I'm not sure how to either move the rest of the elements down without messing up the parallax or bringing the z value of the navbar up above all other elements... Any help would greatly be appreciated!

(I've had this problem on other sites before I've created and I've never been able to figure it out)

[My Website (Github.io) / demo](http://noobularkid.github.io)

Comment: I guess I'm not sure what you're asking, why can't you change the z-value of the nav? Wouldn't the nav be on top the entire time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS `z-index` property to achieve what you're looking for.

Simply add a high `z-index` property value to the navbar selector, like as follows

```
.affix {
    // pre-existing properties
    z-index: 999;
}
```